# How to reduce each child list width by 20px dynamically?

Tags: css

I have a menu and want each child category to be 20px narrower than its parent. The following code works but it's ugly. Can anyone suggest a way to do this dynamically?

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="filetree">
    <li>Category 1</li>
    <li>Category 2
        <ul>
            <li>SUBCAT 1
                <ul>
                    <li>SUBCAT 2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>SUBCAT 3
                                <ul>
                                    <li>SUBCAT 4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 3</li>
    <li>Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS code:

```css
ul.filetree li a {
  width: 440px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul.filetree li ul li a {
  width: 420px;   
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li a {
  width: 400px;  
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li ul li a {
  width: 380px;  
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li ul li ul li a {
  width: 360px;  
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a {
  width: 340px;  
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a {
  width: 320px;  
}
ul.filetree li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a {
  width: 300px;  
}
```

Comment: `width:calc(100% - 20px)` ?

Comment: What is your expected output? How should this look?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-left` for example:

```css
ul.filetree li a {
  width: 440px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul.filetree li ul li a {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filetree">
    <li>Category 1</li>
    <li>Category 2
        <ul>
            <li>SUBCAT 1
                <ul>
                    <li>SUBCAT 2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>SUBCAT 3
                                <ul>
                                    <li>SUBCAT 4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 3</li>
    <li>Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It looks like this now and it works well:

https://imgur.com/a/zW9vi

I hate the lines of CSS reducing 20px for each child and wondered if there was a nicer way to write it.

The idea is that long folder and file names are truncated correctly for the fixed space.